# Run/Convert raw SQL Hierachy using/to Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query that works fine (ms-sql db), but cannot figure out how to run it using a Linq query.  Also I could run it directly in Linq but have no idea in how to convert it to a Linq expression.  Im trying to get all the subordinates for a employee all the way down the management tree.  The table (in brief) is set up like this:
Emp_ID => Guid,
Reports_To => Guid, (The Emp_ID of their manager)
Name_Last, Name_First, etc.....

```
with Hierachy(Emp_ID, Reports_To, Name, Level)
as
(
select Emp_ID, Reports_To, Name_Last, 0 as Level
    from Employees c
    where c.Emp_ID = '5287E80D-8169-4D24-BABD-7639B1D68D59'  ***This should also be a parameter, hard coded here**
    union all
    select c.Emp_ID, c.Reports_To, c.Name_Last, ch.Level + 1
    from Employees c
    inner join Hierachy ch
    on c.Reports_To = ch.Emp_ID
)
select Emp_ID, Reports_To, Name
from Hierachy
where Level > 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please look for other questions on LINQ + hierarchy + (possibly) CTE. This is a continually recurring topic.

Comment: Well I was hoping for a more useful comment.  I did search for hours before and after and still an unable to find a solution using EF Core 3.x.  Forgive my Linq ignorance, hoping someone will provide a little more direction/example/etc.

Comment: There *is* no solution. That's why people keep asking. I can't imagine you didn't find at least some work-arounds. It always depends which one applies best in each situation.